# Add dynamically Hexa decimal code in .xsl file using Database value

Tags: java, xslt, xpath

```
<xsl:template match="">
 <fo:inline  color="#ff0000">
      <xsl:apply-templates select=""/>
  </fo:inline>
```

Here #ff0000 as static but I need to update as dynamically using DB Value.

DB value: `msg = <p><span style="color: #ff0000;">Test</span></p>`
Here `<fo:inline  color="#ff0000">` color is dynamic. p

Answer (score 0):

XSLT operates on XML, and it is not really relevant if the XML values come from the database. But anyway, assuming your XML looks like this:

```
<p><span style="color: #ff0000;">Test</span></p>
```

You could extract the "color" from the style, using this expression

```
normalize-space(substring-after(substring-before(@style, ';'), 'color:'))
```

You could then use Attribute Value Templates to populate the `color` attribute in your output

```
<fo:inline color="{normalize-space(substring-after(substring-before(@style, ';'), 'color:'))}">
```

Try this sample XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:fo="...">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="span">
        <fo:inline color="{normalize-space(substring-after(substring-before(@style, ';'), 'color:'))}">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </fo:inline>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p">
        <fo:block>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Alternatively, if there is a possibility of the "color" not being present, you can do it this way

```
<xsl:template match="span">
    <fo:inline>
        <xsl:if test="contains(@style, 'color')">
            <xsl:attribute name="color">
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-after(substring-before(@style, ';'), 'color:'))" />
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </fo:inline>
</xsl:template>
```